# Special full stop with subequations

Tags: equations, subequations

With this code:

```
Si scriverà, pertanto:

\begin{subequations} \label{eq:laplace-2}
  \begin{align}
    & Z (s^2 M + s C_s + K_s) = Z_u (s C_s + K_s)\\
    & Z_u (s^2 m + s C_s + K_s + K_t) = Z(s C_s + K_s) + K_t Z_r
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

Isolando nella (\ref{eq:laplace-2}a) il termine $ Z_u $, questo risulta pari a:
```

I obtain this result:

[image: without]

**Without** the full stop in the middle. Is possible obtain it using the environment `subequations`?

Comment: Are you sure you want a full stop hanging from nowhere? By the way, there should be no blank line before the `subequations` environment (and no colon after “pertanto”). I'd simply add a comma at the end of the first equation and a full stop at the end of the second one. And I'd use `gather`, rather than `align`.

Comment: Also, you should do `\label{eq:laplace-2first}` in the first row of the `align` (or `gather`) and use `\eqref{eq:laplace-2first}` for the cross reference. This automatically adds the parentheses and takes care of the suffix.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, I will use your useful grammar advices. But, I prefer do not use the `gather' environment, in these equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it is not really difficult, but I don't think the result is pretty, because the period appears to be hanging from nowhere. Just add a row with it and appropriate vertical negative spaces.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\setcounter{equation}{41}

Si scriverà, pertanto,
\begin{subequations} \label{eq:laplace-2}
\begin{alignat}{2}
& Z (s^2 M + s C_s + K_s) = Z_u (s C_s + K_s) \label{eq:laplace-2first} \\[-1.5ex]
&&&\makebox[0pt][l]{\quad.}\notag \\[-1ex]
& Z_u (s^2 m + s C_s + K_s + K_t) = Z(s C_s + K_s) + K_t Z_r
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}
Isolando nella \eqref{eq:laplace-2first} il termine $ Z_u $, questo risulta pari a

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some points to note:

1. there should be no blank line before `\begin{subequations}`;
2. you should use `\eqref`, that takes care of the parentheses;
3. the label can better go in the row you want to refer to, so the reference will automatically get the right suffix;
4. the colon after *pertanto* is wrong and a comma should be used (or no comma at all).

Here's how I'd realize the text, using natural punctuation.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\setcounter{equation}{41}

Si scriverà pertanto
\begin{subequations} \label{eq:laplace-2}
\begin{align}
& Z (s^2 M + s C_s + K_s) = Z_u (s C_s + K_s),\label{eq:laplace-2first} \\
& Z_u (s^2 m + s C_s + K_s + K_t) = Z(s C_s + K_s) + K_t Z_r.
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
Isolando nella \eqref{eq:laplace-2first} il termine $ Z_u $, questo risulta pari a

\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually I'd prefer `gather`, but with the default line width this particular display would not appear correctly centered, because the second equation is a bit too wide.

Comment: Thanks @egreg! And not only for your answers. ;-)